# Print key and values from dictionary to html table (in a certain format) JSON call

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary

The code below is a JSON call which grabs a dict and prints out keys and values to a html table

```
$(function() {
      $('a#search').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/_search', {
          a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
        }, function(data) {
          var tableData = '<table>'
          $.each(data.result, function(key, value){
            tableData += '<tr>' + key + ' ' + '</tr>';
            $.each(value, function(val){
                tableData += '<td>' + val + '</td>';
              });
          });
          tableData += '</table>';
          $('#table').html(tableData);
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

however this prints as follows

```
Developer Publisher ReleaseDate Title
0         1         2
0         1         2
0         1         2
0         1         2
```

it should be printing like this

```
Developer Publisher ReleaseDate Title
0         0         0           0
1         1         1           1
2         2         2           2
```

and I dont know why its missing the contents inside and printing just 0 1 2 so in the end it should print like this

```
Developer      Publisher ReleaseDate Title
Office Kouan   Shouei    ...         ...
Jorudan        Vap       ...         ...
Beam Software  ...       ...         ...
```

any idea to what might be wrong?

Comment: Why did you tagged it as python?

Comment: I am making the call from python with jsonify i guess i didn't have to tag python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the code to :

```
$(function () {
    $('a#search').bind('click', function () {
        $.getJSON('/_search', {
            a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
        }, function (data) {
            var tableData = '<table>'
            $.each(data.result, function (key, value) {
                tableData += '<tr>' + key + ' ' + '</tr>';
                $.each(value, function (val) {
                    tableData += '<td>' + value[val] + '</td>';
                });
            });
            tableData += '</table>';
            $('#table').html(tableData);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

calling `val` in your code is just printing the index not the actual value inside your javascript object, hence using `value[val]`.

Hope this helps. Cheers .. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Any idea about the other part? on why it wont print horizontally? Thanks

Comment: I think your loops are not in proper order. Can you please provide sample `data` from line `}, function (data) {`that you are using to populate table?

Comment: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Developer': ['Office Koukan', 'Jorudan', 'Beam Software'], 'Publisher': ['Shouei', 'VAP', 'Hi Tech Expressions'], 'ReleaseDate': ['March 18, 1994', 'November 18, 1994', 'October 1, 1993'], 'Title': ['Idea no Hi', 'Pachinko Hi Hisshouhou', 'hunThe Hunt for Red October']})

Comment: It is a  defaultdict(list) which is getting returned into JSON with the above content

Comment: I have rewritten a function to generate valid HTML string required to create your table, based on the JSON you provided. You can replace your loops using the one given below. Let me know, if it solves your problem correctly .. :)

Comment: `function generateTable(data){
 var tableData = '<table><tr>';
 var headers = [];
 for(var header in data){
  tableData += '<th>' + header + '</th>';
  headers.push(header);
 }
 tableData += '</tr>'
 for(var i=0; i<data[header].length; i++){
  tableData += '<tr>';
  for(var j=0; j<headers.length; j++){
   tableData += '<td>' + data[headers[j]][i] + '</td>';
  }
  tableData += '</tr>';
 }
 tableData += '</table>';
 console.log(tableData);
}`